# Jetpack Compose BottomSheetScaffold Stop half way

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottom-sheet

I have tried the following code to make my BottomSheetScaffold have a peek height of 92.dp and when pulled up stop halfway or full screen but I does not seem to be accepting the swipeable.  FYI, 92.dp is the minimum height of my sheet when collapsed as to be above a bottom tool bar.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
val swipeableState = rememberSwipeableState(initialValue = 0f)
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    sheetContent = {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Text("Sheet content")
        }
    },
    sheetPeekHeight = 92.dp, // start collapsed
    sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
    sheetBackgroundColor = Color.LightGray,
    sheetGesturesEnabled = true,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .swipeable(
            state = swipeableState,
            anchors = mapOf(
                0f to 0f,
                0.5f to 0.5f,
                0.1f to 0.1f
            ), // define stopping points
            orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
            resistance = null
        )
) {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text("Bottom Sheet Example") }
        )
        Text("Content")
    }
}
```

What I am ultimately trying to do is have the sheet partially visible when the user navigates to the screen and then be able to swipe it all the way down to a minimum height or all the way up to be full screen.

I originally tried this by having a peek height of 200 but then the user cannot swipe it down, only up to full screen.

So, I thought of creating three anchor points so I could have the middle point the initial value and then the user can swipe down to the minimum, or up to full screen.

In the above code I am setting three anchor points but when I swipe up the sheet it goes full screen.

How do you set multiple stops points, or how can I have the sheet visible when the composable appears but yet allow the user to swipe it closed or full screen?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same implementation, but couldn't find any help online. Have you managed to do it?

Comment: Since I did not receive any response here, I sent the same message to the Jetpack Compose team and their response was that it is not supported.  I sort of got into why they provide the anchor points but never got a clear answer.  Anyway, to solve my problem about the user not really understanding the bottom sheet was there we decided to use a short Lottie animation that the user can see when they first go to the screen that has the bottom sheet.  Not ideal, but. does solve the problem and actually looks kind of cool and gives us an opportunity to show other features as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll consider that. Thank you.